# MVC5: Login form in Layout page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm quite new to MVC so please help me understand how to do the following. As you know when you create new MVC5 project it wants you to use Login page as a separate page when you want to log in (i.e. _LoginPartial view with ActionLink to Login controller which returns its View).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the login form throughout the whole site (when user is not logged in yet) so I did the following changes:

**_Layout view:**

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

**_LoginPartial view:**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturlUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-right form-inline", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Username" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Password" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />
}
```

Look like it's working fine when username/password exists, it logs user in and redirects him to home page when ReturnUrl not found in QueryString. However, when it fails to log in it loads original Login view as a separate page because Login controller returns its full view:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View(model);
```

I don't want that. I want to have login form on all pages and be able to log in from any page and just show errors on the page that the user is currently on instead of redirecting him to original Login page. How would I do that without resorting to javascript/ajax?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you even figure that out?

I read your post and the only thing which came to mind is a new controller (or new method in the existing controller) which does not pass the Login page view.Just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I decided to move login part of the code to API Controller and call it from JS which would handle errors and redirection. Part of this explanation is in my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275583/mvc-5-web-api-login-without-bearer-token

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ReturnUrl is Account/Login.
which has been set in web.config

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />

if (user != null)
{
    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

**so, either change loginurl default page or do this in Html.BeginForm().**

```
ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```

It gets current requested page for and sets for ReturnUrl.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-right form-inline", role = "form" }))
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't make a difference. ReturnURL in this case doesn't matter, I can even remove that from the `Html.BeginForm`. Doing `ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` will make sure the user will be redirected to the page he was on before logging in. What I was trying to do is to make sure it doesn't redirect user to /Account/Login View when he enters wrong credentials. This is happening because of `return View(model);` in Login Controller. I need it to not redirect in the case of login failure but rather stay on the current page and display some validation errors